# AutoIT Logging stops after a few days

Tags: logging, scripting, autoit

I run a very simply script to log date and time stamp of how many times I kick an agent off the phone when they are in an unavailable state (logged on to the phone but not "ready" to take phone calls) for too long.

The code (below) that I am using works great, however after a few days (usually 3ish) it stops logging.  The data is going to a text file, to my knowledge there isn't a line limit on a text file, no one is opening the file so it's not in a "read only" state (to my knowledge).  It is (the log file) saved to a shared drive on a server.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

```
$cDate = _NowDate()
$cTime = @HOUR & ":" & @MIN & ":" & @SEC
$TSEntry = ";" & $cDate & ";" & $cTime & ";" & $EMPID & ";" & "1"

Local $hFile = FileOpen("\\somedrive\somefolder\xxx TempCopy\RTALog.txt", 1)

_FileWriteLog($hFile, $TSEntry)
$cDate = ""
$cTime = ""
$TSEntry = ""
```

Comment: Is this your complete script? You just run it to write to the log and the script exits after that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured this out, at least I haven't had any issues (knock on formica) since I added the release line:

FileClose($hFile)